# I am trying to make a header collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a header change when it's scrolling down

html:

```
<div id="header" class="head"> </div>
```

css:

```
.head {
    width:100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: black;
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed !important;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

js:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
    } 
    else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
    }
}
```

for some reason it doesn't work can anyone help!?!?

Comment: maybe try using the correct id: `var header = document.getElementById("header");` ?

Comment: yeah nvm it worked the id was correct something went wrong with my browser so I had to restart it

Comment: really lost my mind then even made a stack overflow account for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var header = document.getElementById('header');
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
    header.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction);
```

```css
body {
  background: red;
  height: 800px;
}

.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: black;
}

.sticky {
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed !important;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="head"></div>
```